# It is showing that name tavail doesnot exist

Tags: matlab, error-handling, rename, cplex, pg-column-does-not-exist-error

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Name "tavail" does not exist.   soclevel.mod    /socvariation   12:10-16 E:/Haripriya/cplexoutput/socvariation/soclevel.mod OPL Outline Problem Marker

> ```
> int t=24;
> int n=20;
> range t=1..tavail;
> range number =1..n;
> float soc[1][number]=[0.6,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.5];
> //forcasted load at 0..4
> float pl[tavail]=[10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000,10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000];
> //target load at 0..11
> float pt[tavail]=[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000];
> //bus voltage at 0..11
> float v[tavail]=[240,232,229,233,230,235,228,234,227,229,231,230,226,232,233,230,236,233,231,232,232,233,233,230];
> //bus voltage at 
> target bus voltage at 0..11
> float vt[tavail]=[230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230];
>
> //decision variable charging power ev
> dvar float pevch[tavail][number] in 0..100000;
> //decision variable discharging power of ev
> dvar float pevdis[tavail][number] in 0..100000;
> dvar float soc[tavail][number] in 0..100000;
> //objective function
> minimize sum(i in tavail)((pt[i]-pl[i])+sum(j in number)-pevch[i][j]+sum(j in number)pevdis[i][j]);
> subject to
>
>  forall(i in tavail,j in number)
>  if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && 0.7<soc[j][i]<0.9&& v[i]<vt[i])
> pevdis[i][j]==soc[j][i]*100000;
>  soc[j][i+1]==0.8*soc[j][i];}
>  else
>  {pevdis[i][j]==0 ;
>  soc[j][i+1]==soc[j][i];}
>
>
>
>  forall(i in tavail,j in number)
>  if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && 0.3<= soc[j][i]<=0.7 && v[i]>vt[i])
>  {pevch[i][j]==soc[j][i]*800000;
>  soc[j][i+1]==1.1*soc[j][i];}
>  else
>  {pevch[i][j]==0;
>
>  soc[i][j]==soc[i][j];}
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Many errors in your model.

The following works better and can help you:

```
//int t=24;
int n=20;
int tavail=24;
range t=1..tavail;
range number =1..n;
float soc[t][number]=[[0.6,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.5]];
//forcasted load at 0..4
float pl[t]=[10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000,10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000,6000000,4000000,15000000,9000000,12000000,6000000,8000000];
//target load at 0..11
float pt[t]=[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000];
//bus voltage at 0..11
float v[t]=[240,232,229,233,230,235,228,234,227,229,231,230,226,232,233,230,236,233,231,232,232,233,233,230];
//bus voltage at target bus voltage at 0..11
float vt[t]=[230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230,230];

//decision variable charging power ev
dvar float pevch[t][number] in 0..100000;
//decision variable discharging power of ev
dvar float pevdis[t][number] in 0..100000;
//dvar float soc[t][number] in 0..100000;
//objective function
minimize sum(i in t)((pt[i]-pl[i])+sum(j in number)-pevch[i][j]+sum(j in number)pevdis[i][j]);
subject to
{
 forall(i in t,j in number:i!=tavail)
 if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && 0.7<soc[i][j]<0.9&& v[i]<vt[i])
{pevdis[i][j]==soc[i][j]*100000;
 soc[i+1][j]==0.8*soc[i][j];}
 else
 {pevdis[i][j]==0 ;
 soc[i+1][j]==soc[i][j];}



 forall(i in t,j in number:i!=tavail)
 if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && 0.3<= soc[i][j]<=0.7 && v[i]>vt[i])
 {pevch[i][j]==soc[i][j]*800000;
 soc[i+1][j]==1.1*soc[i][j];}
 else
 {pevch[i][j]==0;

 soc[i][j]==soc[i][j];}
 }
```

An array is indexed by a range not by a number in OPL.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded. Purchase at http://ibm.biz/error1016.->. socvariation  Unknown OPL Problem Marker
showing like this

Comment: At some point you could either buy CPLEX or go on with using free CPLEX https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/